# Principle Mathematical Induction Product Notation Question?

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing, induction

$$ \prod_{i=1}^n \left( 2i-1 \right) = \left( \frac{(2n)!}{n!2^{n}} \right) $$

My question for this proof is that I am trying to understand product notation and how to factor this question to its lowest form.

$\color{maroon}{Proof :}$

$\text{(i)}\; \; \text{The statement is true for } n = 1 $

$\left ( 2(1) -1) = \frac{2(1)!}{1!*2^{1}} \right) \Rightarrow 1 =1$

$\text{(ii)} \; \; \text{Let } n = k $

$$ \prod_{i=1}^k \left( 2i-1 \right) = \left( \frac{(2k)!}{k!2^{k}} \right) \text{Induction Hypothesis.}$$

$\text{Let } n= k+1 $

$$ \prod_{i=1}^{k+1} \left( 2i-1 \right) = \left( \frac{(2(k+1)!}{(k+1)!2^{k+1}} \right) $$

$ \left( 2(k+1)-1)* \frac{(2k)!}{(k)!2^{k}} \right) $  $\text{From my understanding this multiplies because it is product notation correct?}$

$\Rightarrow (2k+1)\frac{(2k)!}{k!2^{k}}$

This is where I get stuck because I cannot seem to reduce it anymore so that the right and left side equal each other. I am guessing I probably made a mistake with my arithmetic. Can anyone spot my mistake?

Comment: A minor mistake not related. In the first equation of $n=k+1$, the left hand side should still be $2i-1$.

Comment: Your "From my understanding" paragraph has a typo, it should be $(2k+1)\frac{(2k)!}{k!2^k}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've almost got the answer. Just multiply the numerator and denominator by $2k+2$.
$$(2k+1)\frac{2k}{k!2^k}\times\frac{2k+2}{2k+2}$$

Comment: Which part of the problem do I need to do this on the right side or on the left side? I am confused as to where this is referring to. Or is it the result on the bottom?

Comment: @LittleJon  You have \begin{align*} \prod_{i = 1}^{k + 1} (2i - 1) & = \prod_{i = 1}^{k} (2i - 1) \cdot [2(k + 1) - 1]\\ & = \frac{(2k)!}{k!2^k} \cdot (2k + 1) && \text{by the Induction Hypothesis}\\ & =  \frac{(2k)!}{k!2^k} \cdot (2k + 1) \cdot \frac{2k + 2}{2k + 2} && \text{following AlphaGo's suggestion}\end{align*}  Now simplify.